# Using ActiveX objects in Javascript in Linux (in Firefox)

Tags: linux, firefox, activex

It's not quite a "programming" question, but I hope its related closely enough.

Do you know if it is possible to configure the browser in Linux (e.g. Firefox) to use Wine to create ActiveX objects? I would like to handle web pages that use:

```
var xmlDocument = new ActiveXObject( Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0 )
```

etc. in Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can only do that in [Internet Explorer on Wine](http://www.gagme.com/greg/linux/activex-linux.php)

Comment: You could try installing the Windows version of Firefox in Wine.

Linux Firefox, though, you'd have to recompile, with some work to add the Wine check.  I don't think you can do this for client code.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveXObject is part of the Windows Script host, and not available in Linux unless you can use Wine to install it.

As a side issue, the actual ActiveXObject is an instance of a windows application, and not generally available in Linux (especially not the MS Office suite).

Links:

[Windows Scripting Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(VS.85).aspx)

[Wine](http://www.winehq.org/)

Edit: Had Wine confused with Mono. Fixed now.

Comment: what has mono got to do with it? mono is an implementation of .NET

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an xml document you can do that via standard javascript.  Their is no need for ActiveX.  Simply ask the document to parse the xml for you.  Have a look on Mozilla Developers Centre.  They have very good JS docs.

On another note,  if you want cross browser web pages steer clear of ActiveX.  Especailly with all its security holes.

Comment: Hi, if I had control over this page, then I would do it. I just need to link to it, but it doesn't work for Linux guys.

Answer (score 0):

you can see flash in firefox of linux. try used flash.